# Prove the convergence of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $ f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $, with $ f(x) = \sqrt[3]{3x^2 - 2x^3} $

Let $ x_{0} \in (0, 1) $ and $ x_{n + 1} = f(x_{n}), \forall x \in \mathbb{N} $

Prove that $ (x_{n}) $ is convergent and find its limit.

I need to solve this problem using Weierstrass theorem, so I have to find the monotony of the sequence and its upper or lower bound. I tried to find the monotony by calculating $ x_{n + 1} - x_{n} $ and $ \frac{x_{n + 1}}{x_{n}} $, but I got nowhere. As for calculating the bound, I have no idea how it should be done.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What prevents you from derivating $f(x)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $x<f(x)<1$ for all $x\in(0,1)$:
$$
0<x<1\implies 3\,x^2>3\,x^3\implies 3\,x^2-2\,x^3>x^3\implies\sqrt[3]{3\,x^2-2\,x^3}>x.
$$
Also $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $[0,1]$, so that $f(x)<f(1)=1$.

Then $x_0<f(x_0)=x_1<1$, $x_1<f(x_1)=x_2<1$, ...

Comment: Could you, please, elaborate a bit more on this. I don't really know how you get to your conclusion.

Comment: I have included detail in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's all clear now.